# Cannot install RTC Server (JTS + CCM)

Tags: tomcat, installation, rtc, jts, ibm-rational

I'm trying to install **JTS** and **CCM**, I just want to make a few tests, so I download the zip and ran the **server.startup.bat** script, but it takes too long to deploy the **admin.war**, it stays open but I left the console open for 1 day! and there's no new messages in it, the log have the same info from the console, I tried on 3 different machines, 2 with win 7 and 1 with win server 2008, all with 8GB of memory and core i5, so, I don't think is a performance issue, can anybody help me with this?

This are all the messages in the console:

> Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path:
>   C:\JTS5_32bits\server\jre\bin;C:\windows\SysWOW64;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\Infoprint Select;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Personal
>   Communications\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Trace
>   Facility\;C:\RAD\SDP\jdk\bin;. Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"] Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9443"] Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"] Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 766 ms Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25 Feb 12, 2014 1:47:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web
>   application archive C:\JTS5_32bits\server\tomcat\webapps\admin.war

The **catalina.log** file have the same info

Does anyone know how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: You will reach a wider audience of Jazz developers by asking this question @ http://jazz.net/forum.

Scott

Comment: Which version did you download? Have you tried installing using the launchpad.exe from the CLM-Web-Installer-Win-4.0.6? That worked for me